# Event booking for fictional events website

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm in the process of making a fairly straight forward events listing website where users can register and view all listed events (and administrators can set up new events etc).

I wanted to implement a booking system for my current events where the `user` will be able to view a particular event and place an order for a set amount of tickets.

Here's what my `events` table looks like: 
[image]

In order to achieve my goal, will I have to create some sort of link table between `users` and `events` with something like `userID`, `eventID` and `ticketsBooked` columns?

Secondly, how would I be able to implement a booking with PHP/AJAX/MYSQL? I don't know where to begin with this.

EDIT: I know the question is a bit generic but I'll be able to provide some code if required

EDIT 2:

I have a section on my site which allows users to search through my events database table and displays the output of the search like so:

```
echo "<div><a href=\"../php/viewEvent.php?eventID={$event['eventID']}\">".$event['eventName']."</a></div>";
```

The `viewEvent.php` page looks like this:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['userEmail']))
        header("Location: ../login.php");

    require('../includes/conn.inc.php');
    require('../includes/functions.inc.php'); 

    $sEventID = safeInt($_GET['eventID']);

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT eventID, eventName, eventSeries, eventTeams, eventPrizepool, eventStart,  eventEnd, eventWinner, eventRunnerUp, eventLat, eventLong FROM events WHERE eventID = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param('i', $sEventID);

    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->bind_result($eventID, $eventName, $eventSeries, $eventTeams, $eventPrizepool, $eventStart, $eventEnd, $eventWinner, $eventRunnerUp, $eventLat, $eventLong);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="../../media/images/favicon.ico">
<title>View Event Info</title>
</head>
<body>

<table class="tableList">
<tr>
<th>Event Name</th>
<th>Event Series</th>
<th>Number of Participating Teams</th>
<th>Prizepool</th>
<th>Starting Date</th>
<th>Ending Date</th>
<th>Event Winner</th>
<th>Event Runner Up</th>
<th>Event Type</th>
</tr>
<?php
    echo "<tr>";

    echo "<td>{$eventName}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$eventSeries}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$eventTeams}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$eventPrizepool}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$eventStart}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$eventEnd}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$eventWinner}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$eventRunnerUp}</td>";

    if (($eventLat == 0) && ($eventLong == 0))
        echo "<td>Online Event</td>";
    else 
        echo "<td>LAN Event</td>";

    echo "</tr>";

?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Would it be feasible to add a form that has a `ticketAmount` field in it which the user can fill in and press a button for booking? In which case I can store a value in a booking table or something? or the additional column in `users` named ticketsBooked with the event ID as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your first question, you could create a table `user` in which `userId` is a primary key. This would be just user details. Then `ticketsBooked` could be a table, not a column, as this means you can have a ticket ID and two columns to record the user and event ID respectively.

Regarding your second point, your question is just too broad. There would be a lot of work to achieve what you are after, so you need to be more specific.

Comment: Thanks. I came to a solution :)